# Realtime Values in UITableViewCell from UIDatePicker

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UIViewController with two UI Components: UITableView and UIDatePicker. My goal is, to create a screen like the ical->add->Start & End.

I added the the tableView delegate and dateSource to my header file. In the implementation file, I want to display the current value from the datePicker in my tableCell (like the iCal Start & End screen).

My .m looks like the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSMutableArray *dict = [dictionary objectForKey:@"DATA"];


    if(indexPath.row == 1){

        UISwitch *switchSpecifyEnd = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryView = switchSpecifyEnd;
        [(UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView setOn:NO];   // Or NO, obviously!
        [(UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchSpecifyEnd)
                                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }else if(indexPath.row == 3){

        UISwitch *switchOpenEnd = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryView = switchOpenEnd;
        [(UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView setOn:NO];   // Or NO, obviously!
        [(UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchOpenEnd)
                                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }else{

        cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//        NSLog(@"Update Cell: %@",<but how>);

    }

    return cell;

}

- (void)datePickerValueChanged{
    NSLog(@"Logging: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",datePicker.date]);
}
```

How can I update my tableCell with the value from the datePicker?

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For updating your table cell you need to reload your table and when your table will reload then cellForRowAtIndexPath will get call and you can update your cell text.

Suppose this is your method that gets called when you select some date in date picker

```
-(IBAction)setStartTimeMethod
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"];
    self.startTimeString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[timeStartPicker date]]; 
    [dateFormat release];
    [optionsTableView reloadData];
    }
```